# I want the div to be swapped using the CSS and HTML

Tags: css

I want the social to display after BC and header.

You can help using the JSFiddle I created.

So the order should be like

```
BC
Header
social
dfgh.
```

I want this because to swap the content when switched to mobile device.

My html should be the same but you can change the CSS

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  /* Optional, if you want the DIVs 100% width: */
  flex-direction: column;
}

#flex>#a {
  order: 3;
}

#flex>#b {
  order: 1;
}

#flex>#c {
  order: 2;
}

#flex>#d {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="abc">
  <div id="flex">
    <div id="a">social</div>
    <div class="navya" id="navya">
      <div id="b">BC</div>
      <div id="c">Header</div>
      <div id="d"> dfgh</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j35yyy47/9/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this via CSS is to use `display:contents;` which is only supported by Firefox at tis time. https://caniuse.com/#search=contents

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

> **`<display-box>`**
>
> These values define whether an element generates display boxes at all.
>
> **Value** & **Description** below
>
> ---
>
> **contents**
>
> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.
>
> ---
>
> **none**
>
> Turns off the display of an element so that it has no effect on layout (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist). All descendant elements also have their display turned off.
>
> ---
>
> *To have an element take up the space that it would normally take, but without actually rendering anything, use the visibility property instead.*

snippet to test in firefox only

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  /* Optional, if you want the DIVs 100% width: */
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navya {
  display: contents;
}

#flex #a {
  order: 3;
  color:red
}

#flex #b {
  order: 1;
}

#flex #c {
  order: 2;
}

#flex #d {
  order: 4;
}
@supports (display:contents ){
.disclaimer {display:none;}
}
```

```html
<div id="abc">
<p class="disclaimer"><code>display:contents; </code> is not supported in your browser</p>
  <div id="flex">
    <div id="a">social</div>
    <div class="navya" id="navya">
      <div id="b">BC</div>
      <div id="c">Header</div>
      <div id="d"> dfgh</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

render in firefox:

[image: firefox render]

You need to change your html structure by hand or use javascript to do so on the fly

quick example with jquery https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/ or https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

```js
$('#a').insertAfter('#d');
```

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  /* Optional, if you want the DIVs 100% width: */
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navya {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#flex #a {
  order: 3;
  color:red
}

#flex #b {
  order: 1;
}

#flex #c {
  order: 2;
}

#flex #d {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
<div id="flex">
    <div id="a">social</div>
    <div class="navya" id="navya">
      <div id="b">BC</div>
      <div id="c">Header</div>
      <div id="d"> dfgh</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if got the question correct.
From my understanding you want to display the divs' in different order depending on the screen size. ie mobile or web.

If that is the case, I would use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  #flex > #c { order: 2; }
  #flex > #d { order: 4; }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  #flex > #b { order: 1; }
  #flex > #c { order: 2; }
}
```

You just need to update the min and max-width as per your requirements.